# C++ Socket programming Windows

Tags: c++

I wanna set up a socket on a windows machine. For compilation I am using cygwin with the
g++ compiler. For setting up a socket I would need the following library:

WS2_32.lib

which cannot be found on my machine. Is this part of MS SDK or can I download it for free from the web somewhere? If not, is there another way to setup a Socket without winsock.h on
Windows?

Answer (score 3):

Download from the Platform SDK:

[Windows® Server 2003 SP1 Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A55B6B43-E24F-4EA3-A93E-40C0EC4F68E5&displaylang=en#filelist)

or

[Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use native Windows sockets, switch to [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) which is a native Windows C and C++ compiler and comes with all the required libraries.

Answer (score 1):

For Socket programming, [Qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/library/modular-class-library#info_networking) provides a high level library and under L/GPL license.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for Beej's Guide to Network Programming: http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/

BTW:
I am pretty sure MinGW does contain this lib (or something compatible). Are you having problems in linking? This should work "out of the box"

Comment: He's using cygwin, not MinGW.